# C# DrawString() whitespace between letters

Tags: c#, system.drawing

I'm trying to programmatically draw the date in the center of an image.

So far, this works:

```
Font font = new Font("Arial", fontsize);
string[] datestrings = new string[] { dt.ToString("MMMM").ToUpper(), dt.Day.ToString(), dt.Year.ToString() };
for(int i = 0; i < 3; i++)
{
    float textWidth = (int)datemarkGraphics.MeasureString(datestrings[i], font).Width;

    textWidth += (datestrings[i].Length - 1) * spaceBetween;
    float textX = (datemarkImage.Width - textWidth) / 2F;
    float textY = i * (fontsize + 2F);
    datemarkGraphics.DrawString(datestrings[i], font, Brushes.Black, textX, textY);

}
```

However, that results in the letters being a little too close for my liking.  In my research, I found the only way to do this natively was to draw each letter individually, but that makes the letters spaced too far apart:

```
Font font = new Font("Arial", fontsize);
string[] datestrings = new string[] { dt.ToString("MMMM").ToUpper(), dt.Day.ToString(), dt.Year.ToString() };
for(int i = 0; i < 3; i++)
{
    float textWidth = (int)datemarkGraphics.MeasureString(datestrings[i], font).Width;

    textWidth += (datestrings[i].Length - 1) * spaceBetween;
    float textX = (datemarkImage.Width - textWidth) / 2F;
    float textY = i * (fontsize + 2F);
    for (int j = 0; j < datestrings[i].Length; j++) 
    {
        string charToDraw = datestrings[i][j].ToString();
        datemarkGraphics.DrawString(charToDraw, font, Brushes.Black, textX, textY);
        textX += datemarkGraphics.MeasureString(charToDraw, font).Width + spaceBetween;
    }
}
```

Notes:

All numeric variables except for array indexes are floats.

datemarkImageWidth = 228

spaceBetween = 0.3 (though changing this does not seem to change the sapcing on the scale i'd expect, and a negative number still results in extra space between each letter)

fontsize = 28

What am I doing wrong here?  The only thing I can think of is that the MeasureString() function isn't working as I expected, but I'm not sure how.

EDIT: This is not a duplicate of the one linked, it was asking how to do this as well, but they didn't show how they drew each letter individually.

Comment: I looked at that one, and that's where i got the idea to draw each letter separately.  Unfortunately, they didn't show how they did that, so I couldn't figure that part out.

Comment: If the question was still open, it would still be hard to answer because we don't know what the output should look like.  `results in the letters being a little too close for my liking`  What if we don't feel the same way?

Comment: Step one: Do not use Graphics.DrawString but TextRenderer.DrawText ! Step two, center the text by drawing into a rectangle. If you still want to draw the characers measure with typographics param!

Comment: There are [special spacing characters](https://www.compart.com/en/unicode/category/Zs) in Unicode that you can use for more precise spacing.

Comment: The special characters worked, thanks!